# "Route 'HomeScreen' should declare a screen" occuring for one of my components and i dont know why

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have been trying to implement react-navigation to my project to very little success.

Every time i import a screen to the navigator it comes up as "undefined".

I have tried loading just the screen to the top level and it seems to work but when i put it inside the navigation it returns to being undefined.

Heres my code:

index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Root from './navigator/router';
//import Home from './screens/Home';

export class App extends Component {
render() {
    return <Root />;
    }
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
Slider,
Image,
ListView,
ScrollView,
TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import HeatingSliderComponent from '../components/HeatingSliderComponent';

export default class Home extends Component {

_onPressDial = () => {
this.props.navigation.navigate('DialScreen');
};

render() {
return (

  <View style={styles.container}>

    {/* Navigation bar */}
    <View style={styles.navBarOuter}>
      <View style={styles.navBarInner}>

        {/* item 1 */}
        <TouchableOpacity flex = {1}>
          <Image 
            //style={styles.button}
            source={require('../../images/menu_logout.png')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {/* item 2 */}
        <Image
          flex = {3}
          style = {{resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={require('../../images/background_text.png')}
        />

        {/* item 3 */}
        <TouchableOpacity flex = {1}>
          <Image 
            //style={styles.button}
            source={require('../../images/menu_about.png')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>

    <View style = {styles.oneFlexGap}/>

    {/* Main Dial Button */}
    <View style={styles.dialButton}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressDial}> 
        <Image
        //figure out how to make this work and maybe look into making a custom wheel of some kind.
        //probably by writing in native android
          style={styles.button}
          source={require('../../images/menu_edit_4.png')}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

    {/*<View style = {styles.oneFlexGap}/>*/}

    {/* Vertical Slider */}
    {/*<View style = {styles.vertSliderContainer}>
      <HeatingSliderComponent
        step={1}
        minimumValue={0}
        maximumValue={100}
        value={0}
      />
    </View>*/}
  </View>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 5,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
},
navBarInner: {
flex: 1,
flexDirection: 'row',
height: '5%',
width: '100%',
alignItems: 'center',
},
navBarOuter: {
flex: 2,
alignItems: 'center',
},
vertSliderContainer: {
flex: 2,
alignItems: 'center',
},
dialButton: {
flex: 2,
alignItems: 'center',
},
button: {
flex: 1
},
oneFlexGap: {
flex: 1
},
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Home', () => Home);
```

router.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import DialScreen from '../screens/DialScreen';
import Home from '../screens/Home';

export const Root = StackNavigator({
    HomeScreen: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    DialScreen: {
        screen: DialScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'DialScreen',
        },
    },
});
```

I have tried a multitude of things to try and get it to work including making the project again in a new location.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I am still facing these errors but now i am facing the error "Route 'HomeScreen' should declare a screen error.

With my last change i did this to the router.js

```
// import DialScreen from '../screens/DialScreen';
// import Home from '../screens/Home';

var DialScreen = require('../screens/DialScreen');
var Home = require('../screens/Home');
```

and then structured the objects like this

```
DialScreen: {
        screen: DialScreen.DialScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'DialScreen',
        },
```

from these changes i seem to get this error instead.

```
Route 'DialScreen' should declare a screen. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
DialScreen: {
screen: MyScreen,
}
<unknown>
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\validateRouteConfigMap.js:22:6
validateRouteConfigMap
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\validateRouteConfigMap.js:18:21
default
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\StackRouter.js:36:25
default
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-navigation\src\navigators\StackNavigator.js:44:29
loadModuleImplementation
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:174:12
guardedLoadModule
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:119:45
_require
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:110:24
_accept
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:274:12
<unknown>
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:121:27
onmessage
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:101:26
dispatchEvent
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43
<unknown>
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\WebSocket\WebSocket.js:148:27
emit
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\EventEmitter\EventEmitter.js:182:12
__callFunction
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:245:47
<unknown>
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:101:26
__guard
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:213:6
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    C:\Users\Dell\Documents\DSMReact\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:100:17
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpbi3.png)

Comment: hey, place the `<Root />` in the return statement rather than the `<Home />` in the `index.js` file. Try that, let's see

Comment: @ChiamakaNwolisa thats a mistake actually, i was swapping between the two to try render the screen without using the router.

Comment: Pass the navigation prop to the Root like so `<Root navigation={this.props.navigation}/>`

Comment: That doesnt seem to do anything either. The real issue as far as i can see is that the screen: Home part of the router.js is coming up as undefined but i have no idea why or how because everything in Home.js seems to export properly.

Comment: So I assume the home screen shows quite alright. try placing a `console.log` in the home render() to see if the navigation prop lives there

Comment: No you're mistaken, the home screen doesnt show up i just get that error telling me its undefined. i already tried putting a console.log there and it didnt produce anything. before this i was getting the error "Route 'HomeScreen' should declare a screen" if thats any help, going to try reproduce the conditions for the other error right now.

Comment: Wait, I think I see something off. You are registering the `Home` component whilst you should be registering the `App` component. Do you get? Remove this `AppRegistry.registerComponent('Home', () => Home);` from `Home` and instead register the App in your `index.ios.js` or `index.android.js`

Comment: i removed the `AppRegistry.RegisterComponent` in both home.js and dialscreen.js(it was there too) and i was already using `AppRegistry.RegisterComponent` in the index.android.js and index.ios.js.

Comment: does it work now or still having issues?

Comment: still having the same error `got: undefined`

Comment: I've figured it out. Change to this `import { Root } from './navigator/router';
` in the `index.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from this in the `index.js` file

`import Root from './navigator/router';`

to

`import { Root } from './navigator/router';`

and this is because you are doing a named export on the Root StackNavigator.

------------------------------ OR -------------------------------

Instead of the previous solution, you change the export of the `Root` in the router.js file  to a default export like so

`const Root = StackNavigator({...});`

at the bottom, you place the default export statement

`export default Root;`

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, back at it again. None of these changes fix the issue. Going to start looking into my npm packages because its just baffling that i keep having these issues.

Comment: I fixed it. I dont know what i did, i just kept fiddling with everything and then i ran the router again and it worked... thank you for your time though!

Comment: This bug seems to be the bane of my existence with React Native.